# How can I unbind all symbol definitions with a certain prefix?

Tags: elisp, completion, interactive-development

I'm changing up the API of my package pretty frequently, but `company-mode` pulls *every* defined symbol (as it should) in its completions. I don't want to accidentally use an unbound name, so how can I unbind all variables and functions that start with, say, `my-package-`?  After this, I'll simply be able to `load-file` again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [`unload-feature`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Unloading.html#index-unload_002dfeature-924) to undefine all symbols that were defined as part of loading an Elisp source or byte-compiled file. Make sure that your file ends by calling [`provide`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#index-provide-917) at the end. This assumes that you loaded the file with one of the `load` functions or via `require`, it won't undefined symbols defined by `C-M-x` (`eval-defun`) or similar mechanisms.

If you really want to unbind symbols based on their name rather than based on the package that defined them, you can use [`mapatoms`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#index-mapatoms-502) to iterate over all symbols.

```
(mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
            (if (string-prefix-p "foo-" (symbol-name symbol))
                (unintern symbol))))
```

Comment: Useful, but I don't believe this will be effective with interactive development as I describe.  I'm one level deeper than the `feature` system; I'm working only with functions and variables without any explicit grouping.  I have not bothered evaluating `(provide 'my-package)`.

Comment: @SeanAllred I can't think of a good reason not to use `provide`. But anyway, if you really want to do things the dirty way, see my edit.

Comment: Oh, I love `provide`, I just don't think it would work in this case.  Do functions remember what file they were defined in if they were evaluated interactively?

Comment: `unload-feature` has no effect if you evaluate code without loading it from a file (that has `provide`).

Comment: @SeanAllred No, functions only remember where they were loaded from if they were loaded as part of loading a whole file.

Answer (score 7):

- Use `makunbound` to remove the use of a symbol as a dynamic variable (i.e., to void its `symbol-value`).
- Use `fmakunbound` to remove the use of a symbol as a function (i.e., to void its `symbol-function`).
- Use `mapatoms` to iterate over all symbols.  Act on each whose `symbol-name` is matched by the particular prefix you are interested in: call both `makunbound` and `fmakunbound` on it.
- You do not need to `unintern` the symbol, *unless* you are also using completion against symbols themselves, and not just over their use as variables or functions. But if you *do* want to completely remove a symbol then use `unintern`.