# Can I reload a library and have defvar re-assign values?

Tags: variables, defvar

I am developing a library and would like to reload it after editing without exiting Emacs (assume that it is on `load-path`):

```
(load-library "myname")
```

When I do this, Emacs doesn't pick up changes to `defvar`-bound variables.

I don't want to call `eval-defun` (<kbd>C-M-x</kbd>) manually on each top level form.  Does `M-x eval-buffer` respect `defvar`/`defcustom`?

Comment: Maybe `(unload-feature 'myname)` first?

Comment: Just tried it and no, contrary to `eval-defun` it doesn't pick up changes in `defvar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force re-evaluation of a defvar?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-do-i-force-re-evaluation-of-a-defvar)

Comment: @KaushalModi: I don't think it's a duplicate. This question is about acting on all the `defvar`s in a file or buffer, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Drew Check out this solution under that question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2302/115

Comment: @KaushalModi: I see. But (1) the question there is different, even if that particular answer mostly answers this question, and (2) that answer reevaluates more than just `defvar`s. Maybe you would like to create a community question that combines the two?

Comment: Normally one would never need to eval *just* the defvars. Also the OP using `load-file` implies that he wants to evaluate the whole file while making sure that the defvars are reevaluated.

Comment: My own approach is to eval-defun as I change the values. It's infrequent enough to be useable for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(progn (unload-feature 'your-lib) (load-library "your-lib"))`

This will work as long as you first loaded the defvars by loading the library through emacs, and not using `eval-defun`, `eval-buffer` etc.

When you use `require`, `load-library` etc. Emacs will keep track of which variables and functions are part of your library, and will remove them entirely for you when you use `unload-feature`.

When writing packages, I find that using the code above is a better solution than running `eval-defun` as you write new code so you don't get into intermediate states.

Comment: `(info "(elisp) Loading")`, `(info "(elisp) Unloading")` and `unload-feature` require `force` arg if library is dependency for another library. Great answer! I am wondering what Emacs version begin to provide unloading...

Answer (score 3):

`defvar` does not reassign a variable's value in the same way as, say
`setq` or `setf`.  Once a variable has a value, `defvar`
won't touch it.

From `defvar`'s docstring:

> `(defvar SYMBOL &optional INITVALUE DOCSTRING)`
>
> Define SYMBOL as a variable, and return SYMBOL.
>
> ...
>
> *The optional argument INITVALUE is evaluated, and used to set
>   SYMBOL, **only if SYMBOL's value is void.*** If SYMBOL is
>   buffer-local, its default value is what is set; buffer-local
>   values are not affected.  If INITVALUE is missing, SYMBOL's
>   value is not set.
>
> ...

Since you presumably `defvar`ed the variables in question to give them values when you first loaded the library, re-loading the library won't change the values.

See also the elisp manual node on
[Defining Global Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html).

Instead of relying on `defvar`, you can always re-assign values with `setq`.  As an alternative, clunky option, you can `unintern` the symbols so that the `defvar`s will not find them upon reloading:

```
(defvar test-1 "test this")
(defvar test-2 "test this one, too")

test-1                                  ; => "test this"
test-2                                  ; => "test this one, too"

(defvar test-1 "trying to redefine")
(defvar test-2 "trying to redefine, too")

test-1                                  ; => "test this"
test-2                                  ; => "test this one, too"

(mapc #'unintern '(test-1 test-2))

test-1                                  ; => error!
test-2                                  ; => error!

(defvar test-1 "trying to redefine")
(defvar test-2 "trying to redefine, too")

test-1                                  ; => "trying to redefine"
test-2                                  ; => "trying to redefine, too"
```

Comment: In this context, i.e., when developing an elisp package, `defvar` is the correct thing to use. `setq` would clobber customizations set by individual users. OP is asking for a way to force overwriting of `defvar` variables *during package development*. Switching to `setq` would require switching back to `defvar` when the package is released.

Comment: @Tyler, yes, I agree that `defvar` is appropriate for package development.  I'm only pointing out that `defvar` does not re-assign values, while `setq` does.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```el
(defun foo ()
  "(Re-)evaluate all `defvar's in the buffer (or its restriction)."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (when (re-search-forward "\\s-*(defvar \\([^ \t\n(\"]+\\)[ \t\n]+[^)]" nil 'MOVE)
        (let ((old-value (make-symbol "t"))
              new-value value)
          (let ((debug-on-error old-value))
            (setq value (eval-defun-2))
            (setq new-value debug-on-error))
          (unless (eq old-value new-value)
            (setq debug-on-error new-value))
          value)))))
```

That just uses the same code that `eval-defun` uses on a `defvar`.  It traverses the buffer (or its restriction by narrowing), stopping at each `defvar` and using the `eval-defun` code on it.

Answer (score 1):

After I heard that there is no convenient solution for re-evaluation of buffer with reassigning of `defvar`'s I made simple function that relays on `eval-defun`:

```
(defun my/eval-buffer ()
  "Evaluate entire buffer with re-assigning values to `defvar' / `defcustom'.
Useful during package development."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (while (not (eobp))
      (eval-defun nil)
      (end-of-defun))))
```

Code structure inspired by `eval-defun-2` implementation. It is similar to [How do I force re-evaluation of a defvar?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-do-i-force-re-evaluation-of-a-defvar) solution.

Originally I want high level function to re-evaluate library that re-installed through build script so:

```
(defun my/load-library (library)
  "Evaluate entire library with re-assigning values to `defvar' / `defcustom'.
Useful during package development."
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Load library: "
                          (apply-partially 'locate-file-completion-table
                                           load-path
                                           '("" ".el")))))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents (locate-file library load-path '("" ".el")))
    (my/eval-buffer)))
```

*Drew* solution works even on nested `defvar` but it is hard to completely understand code.

I also think about `unintern` all symbols based on symbol prefix/regex (as *Dan* suggested) but I am lazy to type prefix each time... See [How can I unbind all symbol definitions with a certain prefix?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-can-i-unbind-all-symbol-definitions-with-a-certain-prefix)